# Как получать данные из фитнес браслета (F1 plus)

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-le

Как установить соединение и собирать данные?

Comment: Как-то так https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors

Comment: Спасибо, не помогло.